# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not CustomClass in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have just converted my project from swift 4 to swift 5 and received the following error.

I am just wondering why I did not receive this error in swift 4, but swift 5.

It seems that `customErrorData` can be nil, but why next if condition thinks that it is not optional type. I am confused.

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
> 'CustomError'

```
if let customErrorData = try? decoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) 
{
  if let customErrorData = customErrorData {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: `decoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)` returns a `CustomError` - there's no need for a `as CustomError`

Comment: Should I delete the following `if` then?

Comment: `if let customErrorData = try? decoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data) { }`

Comment: IMO you should make your method throw `let customErrorData = try decoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)`

Comment: I have just added else condition, is that enough to take care?

Comment: `JSONDecoder` decode method returns a generic type in this case `CustomError`. If you use `try?` it will return an optional instead of throwing the error in case of failure

Comment: remove the cast `as CustomError?` as well as `if let customError = customErrorData { }`

Comment: If I remove the `if let customError = customErrorData { }` then if `customError` could not able to decode, then what would happen? Would you mind put your answer as a whole please?

Comment: I am not suggesting to use `try?`. You should show your method signature. IMO it should throw. You decide if you want to ignore the error or not when calling it

Comment: Again customErrorData it is not optional. You can't unwrap a non optional type. Just get rid of `if let customError = customErrorData {
    print("custom error message")
  } ` and use `customErrorData` there as you wish

Comment: @LeoDabus, sometimes I receive `customError`, but sometimes not; therefore, if I could not able to decode it as `customError`, then I am showing user a generic message.

Comment: You should use a switch to deal with different types of errors

Comment: I have added the full source code which I am dealing with.

Comment: Regarding "I am just wondering why I did not receive this error in swift 4, but swift 5." Swift would return a double optional in Swift 4 and now it doesn't anymore thats why you get a non optional now

Comment: check this https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/Compatibility.html **The try? expression doesn’t introduce an extra level of optionality to expressions that already return optionals.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224946/discussion-between-casillas-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

when you have

```
as CustomError?
```

it creates an `Optional<CustomError>` (whether or not the underlying thing has value)

You should be able to remove it as `decode(CustomError.self` has all the necessary type info

Comment: If I add  `as? CustomError` and then it shows the following warning `Conditional downcast from 'CustomError?' to 'CustomError' does nothing` as well as same error that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: ahh yea, you don't need any casting here, the `decode(CustomError.self` contains enough info, you should be able to just remove it and have the `try?`

Comment: I kept only the following `try? decoder.decode(CustomError.self, from: data)` and removed `as CustomError?` but still have the same error in the following if condition that I mentioned in the question

Comment: yes, because now you're trying to bind in the following `if`, but it's not an optional type, just remove the if and use the value you unwrapped in the first optional binding statement :)